# htaccess mask for url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, mask

i have a several folders on my hostname-ftp with blog and forum.
so links are 
name.com/blog/
and
name.com/forum/
What i wan't to do is, mask /blog/ url for default access, so when u typing name.com by default it loads from folder name.com/blog/ with mask and whole thing looks only like name.com.
And the forum access leave as it was, name.com/forum without mask.

I'v tried it with this sort of htaccess code: but it makes a total redirecition to /blog/ folder and i can't access any other folder on main host direcotry.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.name\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1
```

Could you please help me to figure out how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified in your rules in any way that you want to keep /forum/ untouched..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.name\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|forum)/
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1
```

Note the difference in the last `RewriteCond`